# jQuery code will not work/apply to elements that are within a file called from an ajax using javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction to an annoying problem.

To summarize before I put the code; I have two files.. a html file with javascript called "bookings.php", and a php file with php "getBookings.php".

The bookings.php file contains all the static information like menus, text etc along with javascript + ajax calls.

I'm calling the getBookings file successfully with javascript/ajax and works well and i don't have any problems with it.

My problem is, that from the file that is loaded (getBookings.php); there are some html elements that i need to toggle. The jQuery for it, I have included in the bookings.php file.. but the jquery won't apply or work when the ajax file is called.

All the contents on getBookings.php gets loaded into an #bookingSummary element.

Now, my code is very long, so i will include all the important parts..

```
// Usual Head Content, Meta, CSS, jQuery files
// Filters
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function bookings()
{
    var fltr="";
    if(document.frm.bkid.value != "")
        fltr+='bkid='+document.frm.bkid.value+'&';

    if(document.frm.customer.value != "")
        fltr+='cid='+document.frm.customer.value+'&';

    if(document.frm.site.selectedIndex != 0)
            fltr+='sid='+document.frm.site.value+'&';

    if(document.frm.status.selectedIndex != 0)
        fltr+='st='+document.frm.status.value+'&';

    if(document.frm.supp.selectedIndex != 0)
        fltr+='sup='+document.frm.supp.value+'&';   

    if(document.frm.datefrm.value != "")
        fltr+='dfrm='+encodeURI(document.frm.datefrm.value)+'&dto='+encodeURI(document.frm.dateto.value);   

    document.getElementById('bookingsummary').innerHTML="<br /><p align='center'>    <img src='img/bigloading.gif'></p>";
    url='get/getBookings.php?'+fltr;
    getAjaxRec(url, viewbookings);

}


function viewbookings()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && (xmlHttp.status==200 ||     window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
    {
        document.getElementById("bookingsummary").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }   
 }

</script>
```

The Above code is the javascript that all works fine.. the following is the html code that calls the above function - bookings():

```
<!-- Several Form fields are here..-->
<input type="button" value="Apply Filter"  class="searchBtn" onClick="bookings();">


<!-- Show booking results -->
<div id="bookingsummary"></div>
```

Now, within the getBookings file there is an html element with a class name "hiddenDetails" that i need to toggle and the Jquery for it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('.bookingKeyDetails').click(function()
  {         
        $(this).next('.hiddenDetails').slideToggle('medium");
  });

 });
</script>
```

The above code all works apart from the jquery.. here is a snippet from the getBookings.php file.. the part i want to apply the jquery to..

```
<?php
// A while loop happens then..
$result="           
<div class=\"bookingKeyInfo\">
<div class=\"lb1\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=sup1x".$rw['id']." ></div>
<div class=\"lb2\"><a href=\"editbooking.php?id=".$rw['id']."\">".$rw['id']."</a>     </div>
<div class=\"lb3\">".date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rw['pickupDate']))." <strong><font     color=\"#FF0000\">".date('H:i', strtotime($rw['pickupTime']))."</font></strong></div>
<div class=\"clearLeft\"></div>
</div>

<div class=\"bookingKeyDetails\">
<div class=\"b-one\"><img style=\"margin-top:9px; padding-bottom: 5px;\"     src=\"$base_dir/img/".strtolower($rw['status']).".png\"></div>
<div class=\"b-two\"><img id=\"isCustomerEmailed\" style=\"margin-top:9px; padding-    bottom: 5px;\" src=\"$base_dir/img/unassigned.png\"></div>
<div class=\"b-three\"><img id=\"isSupplierEmailed\" style=\"margin-top:9px; padding-    bottom: 5px;\" src=\"$base_dir/img/unassigned.png\"></div>
<div class=\"b-four\"><img id=\"isSupplierConfirmed\" style=\"margin-top:9px; padding-    bottom: 5px;\" src=\"$base_dir/img/unassigned.png\"></div>    
<div class=\"b-trip\">".substr($rw['DA'],0,6)."..<strong> to </strong>     ".substr($rw['DB'],0,6)."..</div>
<div class=\"b-pax\">".$rw['pax']." Pax</div>
<div class=\"b-cost\">&euro;$cost </div>
<div class=\"b-supplier\">".substr($sup,0,10)."..</div>

<div class=\"clearLeft\"></div>

<div class=\"hiddenDetails\">More Booking Information...</div>
</div>";

echo $result;
?>
```

I know this is a very long description of the problem.. so I have tried to give my code exactly as it is..

Could anyone shed some light, as to why the jQuery isn't working.. cz it works separately, just not on any element that is called from getBookings..

Comment: If you're using jQuery anyway, why are you mucking about with `xmlHttp.readyState` and the like? The whole point of jQuery is to abstract away all of that messiness.

Comment: I agree with that notion, i've been fairly new to jQuery/ajax but im a quick learner never the less, so will be looking to improve upon that by superceding it with clean jQuery - would prefer to do that when im the boss of jQuery ;)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're binding an event handler with jQuery to `bookingKeyDetails` before it actually exists on the page. Remember that this element is being added to your html only after the page is loaded, so any actions you make in `$(document).ready(function() {` will not apply to it.

Bind the event handler only after you change the html:

```
function viewbookings() 
{
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && (xmlHttp.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
  {
    document.getElementById("bookingsummary").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    $('.bookingKeyDetails').click(function()
    {         
      $(this).next('.hiddenDetails').slideToggle('medium');
    });
  }   
};
```

Comment: You sir, as they say, are THE MAN! ;).. It works and makes sense what you just explained.. I am fairly new to jQuery/ajax reason why i wasn't too sure on how I could actually load the jQuery after the file had been called.. and looking at your code now.. i feel stupid lol. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: No problem, I also really recommend switch to jQuery ajax before you go on, it's very easy to implement and will make these kind of bugs even easier to detect and fix.

Comment: Definitely will be. Just tryna grasp as much as i can.. for me, its about understanding whats actually happening between the code opposed to just get the "answer". Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since the HTML element you need to toggle was never on the page when the calling page instantaiate the jQuery to toggle, you need to reinitialize the function after a successful call from your ajax.

You can use jQuery .success callback function for their AJAX call tools...  I use that to help with this kind of processing instead of native AJAX. Makes life simpler and better cross browser support.

Just call your toggle function after the success.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You're using single and double quotes in your function call

```
$(this).next('.hiddenDetails').slideToggle('medium");
```

user `'medium'` or `"medium"`

Answer (score 0):

It's very obvious that it will not toggle because you have writtent the Jquery in the "bookings.php". During the page load of bookings.php, it will not find any content of the getBookings.php so that Jquery will not apply as no element is available with that id.

You have to bind the event for the toogle on Ajax success event of the when you are calling for getBooking.php.

```
 $.ajax({
      url: URL,
      success: function(){
          $('.bookingKeyDetails').click(function()
          {         
             $(this).next('.hiddenDetails').slideToggle('medium");
          });
    },
      error: function(){
        alert('failure');
      }
    });
```